# BeautifulSoup can't get all source code of the page, only a little lines

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page_origin = urlopen("https://stackoverflow.com")
page_html = page_origin.read()
page_origin.close()
print(page_html)
```

> The result is the full html code of https://stackoverflow.com. It works fine. Because it's too long enough, I don't paste it on.

The problem is with BeautifulSoup. I add two lines' code to use BeautifulSoup to analyze the html. Strange things happened. It didn't work at all.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page_origin = urlopen("https://stackoverflow.com")
page_html = page_origin.read()
page_origin.close()
# print(page_html)

page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, features="lxml", from_encoding="gbk")
print(page_soup)
```

The result is very very simple.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="html__responsive">
 <head>
  <title>
   Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, &amp; Build Careers
  </title>
  <link href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d" rel="shortcut icon"/>
  <link href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a" rel="apple-touch-icon image_src"/>
  <link href="/opensearch.xml" rel="search" title="Stack Overflow" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml"/>
 </head>
</html>
```

It's not the full code of html and I can't analyze it at all.

Please help me, I debug it for too much time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This gives the full source code for me:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Comment: I tested your code and get the error:  `self.is_xml = builder.is_xml`
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_xml'`

Comment: Try 'html.parser' instead of 'lxml'